# gridview item scale to more bigger

Tags: android, gridview

I have a requirement for my app, I use grid view display all the app icons,  and when focused, I want to the focused item scale bigger a little, I use below code in adapter getView callback.

```
/*
if(selectItem==position){
    convertView.setScaleX(1.2f);
    convertView.setScaleY(1.2f);    
}
else {
    convertView.setScaleX(1.0f);
    convertView.setScaleY(1.0f);
}
*/
return convertView;
```

This only works for scaling item, the focus border is not scaled accordingly. thanks for any help. did I do it wrong way? how to scale gridview item and the focus border?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use frame layout as the root and then a Grid View followed by an invisible Image View, so you are initially hiding the full screen ImageView and showing it on click on the Grid Item. As all the Views in a frame layout are stacked one on other we can display a View over another View.

More info here:

http://techiedreams.com/android-custom-grid-view-with-zoom-in-animation-effect/

:)